# Binary multiplication of Base-2

Tags: binary, multiplication, cpu-architecture

In base-2 system, ie. Binary system. 0*0=0, 1*1=1, 1*0=0. But what is 2*1=? and 2*0=? And in binary multiplication, that's booths' algorithm, what should we do when we have to multiply the multiplicand with -2 and +2? Eg. 10001 * -2

Comment: There is no 2 in binary. If you meant 10, then 10*1=10.

Comment: I think you're confused between the value 2, and two's complement of a value. They're not the same thing. Try looking into the latter, it might make things more clear.